# Annual review while changing careers

Tags: career-switch, careers, burnout

### Background:

I've been in the same industry a long time and the same company for longer then the industry average turnover period. I'm past the burning out phase and I'm chronically unhappy with my career.

I am in the process of a total career change, mostly being held up by process of getting a small business loan and legal processes that will take a while. I'm holding my current position until I'm done.

### And the question:

Here's the kicker. Hope do I fill out a self assessment and go through  a review when my mind really isn't in the job like it should be?

I'm not a particularly good liar; acting like this isn't going on is next to impossible for me.

Comment: If you're having trouble going through the review process due to your mindset, that seems more like a psychological issue than a workplace one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Hope do I fill out a self assessment and go through a review when my
>   mind really isn't in the job like it should be?

Fill out the self assessment **as if for some reason your plans to leave will fall through** and your time there will be extended. As painful as it may be, you need to just push through this and finish the self assessment as *completely and accurately* as you can.

Comment: Yes, just hold on and push through, do the assessment, **search for jobs ASAP** and remember there is life outside the workplace

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question, I suspect you alreday know that:
The Professional thing is to either commit to your job or hand in your notice. So until you have sufficient financial security for your personal taste you'll have to go through with it. Treating a job which is **probably but not certainly** short-lived as if you would stay there longer is not the same as lieing though. Rest assured your employer won't inform you when he is evaluating or preparing to fire you either!